# How to make a number field increment by one as per a certain criteria?

Tags: workflow

On the `Task` object, I have to create a field "Barcode Number"( `Bar_Code_Number__c`), which starting from a specific value 68992001 and for every created task on any object increment to one, when the Task `subject` is " PTT Dispatch Task" only. For other task subject , it should be blank. Also, the users can also edit this field if they want. But the next task creation will follow the regular increment number ( and not from the one what the user has changed). Can you plz suggest how to achieve it. Thanks

I tried a workflow rule but did not succeeded.

As per the WF I created, the criteria as Task subject as " PTT Dispatch Task" , and formula as below, and first time i inputted the number above first number here. But i think this is not the correct way.

[image: Formula]

Comment: see https://salesforcesidekick.com/2016/03/28/how-to-create-a-conditional-auto-number/

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in many places:

**IDEA** - [Provide conditional auto-numbering](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq7J)

**Process Builder** - [How to Create a Conditional Auto Number with just Process Builder](https://salesforcesidekick.com/2016/06/27/how-to-create-a-conditional-auto-number-with-just-process-builder/).  This is kind of clever in a way - you link the subject Object via a lookup relationship to another object that has an auto-number field. Each time your subject object should get an incremented number, you insert the auto-number object, then take the autonumber field from the auto-number object and smash it back into your subject object.

**Flow** [How to Create a Conditional Auto Number](https://salesforcesidekick.com/2016/03/28/how-to-create-a-conditional-auto-number/) - same as above

**APEX** In an after update/insert trigger on your subject SObject, you can use `(SELECT ... FOR UPDATE)` on a custom object and increment a custom field `Next_Sequential_Number__` by one. This gives you maximum flexibility if you need multiple numbering ranges, say, by business unit or product line.