# Implement a Counter to track records by record type

Tags: process-builder, record-type, automation

I have an object called 'Protocols' with 5 record types that will produce 5 types of documents. For each type, I need to track the number of documents that have previously been published, e.g. Protocol Lease #00001, Protocol Incident #00001, Protocol Return #0001, etc.

If each type was in a separate object, this could have been done through autonumber on record name. Not the case here.

It seems like custom metadata and custom settings cannot be updated with a trigger or process.

I am wondering if there is a way to create global variables that can be updated programatically?

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a object with one record, this record can be treated as global variable and update the value accordingly.

Comment: Could you use a trigger on the 'Protocols' object that generates a number before insert on a newly created record? The trigger could query for a record with the most recent Created field and the record type that you're looking for, and then take the most recently created record's field and add 1 to it.

The main issues you would run into would be bulkifying this action and preventing race conditions.

Comment: P.S. You'll want to vote for [this feature](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bq7J).

Comment: There are two options I am now considering 

- [the idea here] (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157225/how-to-make-a-number-field-increment-by-one-as-per-a-certain-criteria)

- A roll-up summary on an account that is on every protocol (org) from a child object "counter". Process builder creates a new counter record whenever a protocol is created. However, the first answer has the advantage of not using objects.