# SOQL to return COUNT value via Apex

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am trying to return the SOQL listed values into a field using an Apex Trigger:-

**Object**:

1. Name = `RPA__c`

**Fields**:

1. `Business_Area__c` (picklist) VALUES = Finland Managed Services, UK Managed Services
2. `Business_ID_Number_HIDDEN__c` (Number field) VALUES = integer

**SOQL**:

```
List<AggregateResult> lstResult =   [SELECT Business_Area__c value, Count(Id)  
                                    FROM Records_of_Processing_Activities__c 
                                    GROUP BY Business_Area__c];
```

So, the SOQL is returning as below:-

```
**Business Area                Count(id)**
Finland Managed Services       5
UK Managed Services            3
```

This is working perfectly and returns the correct count of the records where "Business Area" contains "Finland Managed Services" (3)

BUT

I am really struggling to capture that `Count(id)` and add it into a field in the `RPA__c` object (`Business_ID_Number_HIDDEN__c` is the field to apply the value into)

So:- I have written this so far, but is not returning the `count(id)` into the `Business_Area__c` field:-

```
trigger BATrigger on RPA__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    List<AggregateResult> lstResult =   [SELECT Business_Area__c value, Count(Id)  
                                        FROM RPA__c 
                                        GROUP BY Business_Area__c];
}
{
    List<Records_of_Processing_Activities__c> Business_ID_Number_HIDDEN__c = new List<Records_of_Processing_Activities__c>();
    for(AggregateResult result:lstResult);
}
    {
if (lstResult == 'Finland Managed Services') {
    Business_ID_Number_HIDDEN__c = Count(Id);
} else if (lstResult == 'UK Managed Services') {
    Business_ID_Number_HIDDEN__c = Count(Id);
} else {
    Business_ID_Number_HIDDEN__c = null;
}
    }
    update Business_ID_Number_HIDDEN__c; 
}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, again, very new to this so please be constructive in your appreciated help!

Comment: Hi Andy, welcome to SFSE. It's a bit unusual to roll up a record count onto the record itself - here you have counts of `RPA__c` records rolling up onto each `RPA__c` records.  That structure *can* cause some problems. Have you considered approaching this need with a Summary Report? What's driving this data model choice?

Comment: Hi David,thanks for the quick response. Yes, it's indeed a tough one... in simple terms, we need to have a unique ID that is associated against each record, this will need to be derived from the above (poor) attempt :) I will try to articulate the expected results below:-

Comment: we cannot use Master Detail (as its a single object needed and no parent child, we cannot use a filter/condition on AutoNumber fields (SFDC limitation) and must have each Business area "count() sequention based on the picklist value, not the record count (if only life was that easy!!)

Comment: hence the sequential value against each record based on the Business Area and # of records where Business area = Finland Managed services OR UK Managed Services. 2 days into Apex and counting!! :D

Comment: It would be helpful to add all of that relevant detail to the body of your question. Filtered auto-numbers come up a lot; this question is probably a duplicate: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157225/how-to-make-a-number-field-increment-by-one-as-per-a-certain-criteria

Answer (score 5):

The default way to access espressions is `expr0` for the first, `expr1` for the second, and so on. A preferable way for most is to use an *alias*.

Adding an alias would work as below.

```
SELECT Business_Area__c, count(Id) recordCount
FROM MyObject__c WHERE ...
```

The actual retrieval of this attribute would work as below.

**Without Alias**

```
Integer count = result.get('expr0');
```

**With Alias**

```
Integer count = result.get('recordCount');
```

Comment: Thanks for this Adrian, will try it now...